# how to use operationqueue to first make API call then second use a URL from that API call?

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

The following code is being used to add dependency using OperationQueues:

```
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.main
    let operation1 = BlockOperation(block: {
        self.makeAPICall()
    })
    let operation2 = BlockOperation(block: {
        self.fetchImage(imageURL: modelObject.imageURL)
    })
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation2)
    operation2.addDependency(operation1)
```

I'm getting a threading error inside operation2 block. am I missing something. Could you please help. Thank you.

> Project was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
>   (lldb) bt
>   * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
>     * frame #0: 0x0000000104df1198 Project`ViewController.(viewDidLoad() -> ()).(closure #2) [inlined] function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Project.ViewController.(viewDidLoad () -> ()).(closure #2) at ViewController.swift:61 [opt]
>       frame #1: 0x0000000104df1198 Project`ViewController.(viewDidLoad() -> ()).(closure #2) at ViewController.swift:60 [opt]
>       frame #2: 0x0000000000000008
>       frame #3: 0x00000001064b53b7 Foundation`**NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7

Comment: Does the API call `self.makeAPICall()` use async or sync way?

Comment: Can you tell me your modelObject is Global variable or local variable

Comment: I think you have to add self.modelObject.imageURL instead of modelObject.imageURL

Comment: @MandeepSingh modelObject is persistent class which is static and available throughout the application. Thank you.

Comment: @asdiu Can you show me the error. So that I can help you

Comment: @MandeepSingh thank you, I will update the main post with error.

Comment: @MandeepSingh backTrace results have been added to the main post. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156034/discussion-between-mandeep-singh-and-as-diu).